# How to add "after" method in AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm trying to understand how AspectJ works. To begin I want to add a method called `after`, calling usual existing using AspectJ.

myClass can be seen below:

```
package myclass;
public class MyClass {

    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("methode1 is called");
    }

    public void method2(String str){
        System.out.println("methode2 is called " + str);
    }
}
```

After method2 I want to show some text message and argument `str`:

```
package myclass;

public aspect aspect2 {
    pointcut func(String str): 
        call(myclass.MyClass.method2(String)) &&  args(str);
    after(String str) : func(str) {
        System.out.println("Aspect from method2: " + str );
    }
}
```

Finally to call it there is main class `entrypoint`:

```
package myclass;
public class entrypoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.method1();
        mc.method2("zzz");
    }
}
```

As an input, it shows :

```
methode1 is called
methode2 is called zzz
```

It does not show `Aspect from method2: zzz`, so aspect doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in your point cut add the return type (void include) and in the advice add returning like after(String str) returning : func(str)

Comment: @JEY thank you sir, it works!

Comment: @JEY, please convert your comment into an answer which can be accepted by the OP in order to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I post my comment as an answer as @kriegaex ask.
You have some mistake in the code:
 1. In the pointcut you forgot to add the return type even if it's void you should specified it.
 2. In the advice add returning `after(String str) returning : func(str)`

```
package myclass;
public aspect aspect2 {
        pointcut func(String str): call(void myclass.MyClass.method2(String)) &&  args(str);
    after(String str) returning : func(str) {
        System.out.println("Aspect from method2: " + str );
    }
}
```